# Re-running an initialization function for each api reload

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I am currently running an api project (`fastapi` served with `uvicorn`) where at startup a series of initializations are done.

If I set `reload=True` as an argument to my `uvicorn` startup function, my api correctly recognizes code changes and reloads. The issue is that I don't get the initializations when reloading the api, and this ends up breaking my workflow and effectively blocking me from using what I consider a very useful feature.

Example:

```py
# fastapi app object is located in another module

def main() -> None:
    various_initializations()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    uvicorn.run("my.project.location.for:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=my_port, reload=True)
```

In this case I need my `main` function to be run at each reload.

Edit:

Testable example

`main.py`

```py
import uvicorn

from my_class import MyClass


def init_stuff() -> None:
    MyClass.initialize()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_stuff()
    uvicorn.run("api:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=10000, reload=True)
```

`my_class.py`

```py
class MyClass:
    initialized = False
    
    @staticmethod
    def initialize() -> None:
        MyClass.initialized = True

    @staticmethod
    def do_stuff() -> None:
        if not MyClass.initialized:
            raise ValueError("not initialized!")

        print("doing stuff")
```

`api.py`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

from my_class import MyClass

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/stuff")
def api_stuff() -> None:
    return MyClass.do_stuff()
```

When `reload=False`, if I hit the `/stuff` endpoint I get a correct behavior (`doing stuff` is printed on the terminal). With `reload=True` I get an exception indicating that `MyClass` hasn't been initialized (`ValueError: not initialized!`)

Comment: This is a bit vague. Do you get any errors? What kinds of initializations are you referring to? Do they include imports? Please try elaborating a bit more. There is no reproducible code to work with. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @alec_djinn fair enough, gimme a minute to produce a runnable sample :)

Comment: @alec_djinn here it is!

Comment: You are not instantiating your object but just importing it, are you sure this code will work?

Comment: Yes those methods are both static (forgot the decorator), as in my original class. In any case that's not really the scope of the question, I need to be able to run a function any time the api gets reloaded

Comment: Have you tried hooking the `startup` and `shutdown` events? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/

Comment: That's it! I couldn't find a way to look for that specific functionality, hooking on the `startup` event worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @MatsLindh suggested, the (a?) way to do it is to hook on the `startup` event of `fastapi`, making the initialization run on each reload.

my `main.py` file now looks like this:

```py
import uvicorn

from my_class import MyClass
from api import app

@app.on_event("startup")
def init_stuff() -> None:
    MyClass.initialize()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("api:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=10000, reload=True)
```

*Happy api noises*